# Want to select specific window (object cloning) in automation anywhere 11.2

Tags: object, automation, window, cloning, automationanywhere

[Please find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inSK2.png)I am automating a task, in that I will use a excel addin (Example addin name is AAA). While running the task it will open multiple windows but with the same name(Prompt box 1 name is AAA, Prompt box 2 name is AAA). So when I am using object cloning in Automation anywhere I need to select the window name. As all the windows name is same (three windows with the name AAA) it is not working properly.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Expected result: I need to differentiate the windows in Automation anywhere
Current result: AA will click on wrong window.

Comment: How do you identify each window as human? There is must be something you can use as search criteria in the object cloning command.

Comment: Manually when I am using I can differentiate because only the windows names is same, contents & size of the windows are all different.
But automation anywhere will go by window's name

Comment: Can you show some screenshots? Or a gif animation? It will be useful.

Comment: I added the screenshot. Please find it in the description.

Answer (score 0):

**Recap:** You are clicking on a button on the first window that opens another window with the same name and you need to do some action on the second window.

**Therefore the solution is:** Use **currently active window**  within the select window dropdown menu in the object cloning command.